# backbonejs, edge browser and change event

Tags: backbone.js, microsoft-edge, blur

This app was built with backbone and everything seems to work fine on every browser except edge. When you tab from one input to another (changing the value of the current input) the app simply stops working and then crashes.

This line '**change** input[name=formHeight]' : 'updateFormSize', if I change this to  '**blur** input[name=formHeight]' : 'updateFormSize', seems to work on edge. Do you know if there's any issue with edge, any clues or ideas to solve this.

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Seems Edge does not trigger `change` as per [this bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15181565/)